# Is it possible to use cloud formation to deploy a Cloud9 ide on an EC2 image that is not obsolete?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, cloud9-ide, cloud9

Apparently Cloud9 out of the box is being shipped on an essentially obsolete EC2 instance, as it does not have a current, recent, or viable instance of the aws cli.

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.19.112 Python/2.7.18 Linux/4.14.296-222.539.amzn2.x86_64 botocore/1.20.112
```

As far as I can tell, Amazon recommends using version 2.9.1;
But even the most recent series 1 version is 1.27.19

Is there any way of using CloudFormation to deploy Cloud9 on a more contemporary EC2 instance? I want to roll Cloud9 out to a dev organization, but it is distressing to me that it seems to be deployed crippled (and yes, I need to use more recent cli options for the initial configuration of each new IDE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with the identifier for the **Amazon Machine Image** (AMI)?

> That's used to create the `EC2` instance, because to declare this entity in your **AWS CloudFormation template** need use this syntax in your `JSON` file:

```json
{
  "Type" : "AWS::Cloud9::EnvironmentEC2",
  "Properties" : {
      "AutomaticStopTimeMinutes" : Integer,
      "ConnectionType" : String,
      "Description" : String,
      "ImageId" : String,
      "InstanceType" : String,
      "Name" : String,
      "OwnerArn" : String,
      "Repositories" : [ Repository, ... ],
      "SubnetId" : String,
      "Tags" : [ Tag, ... ]
    }
}
```

Then, to choose an AMI for the instance, you must specify a valid '**AMI alias**' or a valid **AWS Systems Manager path**, the default AMI is used if the parameter isn't explicitly assigned a value in the request.

Check the entire process in the [AWS Cloud9 environment EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloud9-environmentec2.html).

> > **AMI aliases**
>
> - Amazon Linux (default): amazonlinux-1-x86_64
> - Amazon Linux 2: amazonlinux-2-x86_64
> - Ubuntu 18.04: ubuntu-18.04-x86_64
>
> > **SSM paths**
>
> - Amazon Linux (default): resolve:ssm:/aws/service/cloud9/amis/amazonlinux-1-x86_64
> - Amazon Linux 2: resolve:ssm:/aws/service/cloud9/amis/amazonlinux-2-x86_64
> - Ubuntu 18.04: resolve:ssm:/aws/service/cloud9/amis/ubuntu-18.04-x86_64

Comment: This looks like the data I need, Gonzalo! Thank you. I'm still kind of gobsmacked that Cloud9 comes with obsolete images out of the box, but with some elbow grease this should get the job done.

Comment: Yes I understand you, anyway no problem, you're welcome @Blunt Jackson